# What is the architecture of application

Tags: oop, architecture

I was new to programming and came across the term of "architecture" of an application. Is it true that architecture of application is when application logic is divided into classes thanks to the use of object-oriented programming? Please guys I really need your help

Comment: Normally it refers to a computer's architecture, like x86, x64, ARM, etc . Would probably help to have some context thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Software architecture** is the ways of each part of the sofware itself is structured and how these parts comunicate each other. There is no silver bullet of software architecture and yes, there are a lot of ways to do it. Depending what you need, in general comertial solutions it can envolve (and many more):

- Programming Paradigm (Oriented Object, Structural, Functional, Aspect);
- Platforms such as Java, .Net, Node, etc.
- Databases structures;
- Schema for oriented object model based on classes and relational model on databases;
- How the application access storages (databases, files, etc.), what providers it will be used and how it is implemented;
- How the application provide and share information (Rest API);
- The formats that software can read (json, xml, soap etc..);
- How Back-end and Front-End applications communicate;
- How application deals with authentication and authorization;
- The UI implementations (html, js, css, etc..);
- Stack and frameworks for Front-end and Back-End (.net, java, node/js, ruby, python, angular, react, etc.)

A good software architecture is one that fits the problem to be solved.

`S.O.L.I.D.` is a very important topic inside the OOP and I recommend you to understand what is each letter in the topic and tries to base your OOP implementations on it.

Here is a sample os a `n-tier architecture` which is a classical architecture that organize your file/classes/projects. The picture shows `Java` keyword but it is not exclusive for it, it is a concept for any platform.

[image]

You also can think about the the **Solution Architecture** that in my option is realted beyond the software. It is related about the environment execution, infrastructure such as cloud or local servers, the external providers (external APIs and how you access them), the software itself, databases environments, etc.

This post refers my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Application Architecture is the process of defining the framework of an organization's application solutions against business requirements.

In Object-Oriented Programming, application complexity is divided into Classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a part of the truth.

Imagine you are asked to build a house from scratch. You would need multiple schematics like the foundation of the ground work, gas pipelines, sewer layout,  interior and exterior designs, and you would like to know how to wire the building (electricity, internet, ..) before you start building. All of this is architecture too. The same principles apply to software applications and groups of applications; in IT there are software architectures, Enterprise Architectures (corporation wide), data platform architectures etc.